# How to get the index of a dynamic List / ForEach bindable element (new Xcode 13's syntax)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, xcode13, swiftui-foreach

Until now, to setup bindings between the elements in a dynamic collection and the rows of a List we had to do like that :

```
List(Array(zip(data.indices, data)), id: \.1.id) { index, _ in
    HStack {
        Text((index + 1).description)
        TextField("", text: Binding(
            get: { data[index].text },
            set: { data[index].text = $0 }
        ))
    }
}
```

We need : the index of the element for the binding ; + the element identifier for the `List` (to avoid weird animations) ; and a custom `Binding` to avoid a crash when deleting the last row.

It's complicated (and I'm not sure it's very efficient).
Since WWDC21, we have a new syntax (which can be back-deployed):

```
List($data) { $item in
    HStack {
        Text("Index ?")
        TextField("", text: $item.text)
    }
}
```

It's cleaner.

But while it is strongly recommended to use this new syntax, it would be nice to be able **to access the element's index in the closure**. Do you know how we can do it?

## EDIT :

I tried this (it works), but I feel like it's not the right way to do it :

```
let d = Binding(get: {
    Array(data.enumerated())
}, set: {
    data = $0.map {$0.1}
})
List(d, id: \.1.id) { $item in
    HStack {
        Text("\(item.0 + 1)")
        TextField("", text: $item.1.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build wrapper by yourself:

```
struct ListIndexed<Content: View>: View {
    let list: List<Never, Content>
    
    init<Data: MutableCollection&RandomAccessCollection, RowContent: View>(
        _ data: Binding<Data>,
        @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) where Content == ForEach<[(Data.Index, Data.Element)], Data.Element.ID, RowContent>,
    Data.Element : Identifiable,
    Data.Index : Hashable
    {
        list = List {
            ForEach(
                Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
                id: \.1.id
            ) { i, _ in
                rowContent(i, Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        list
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ListIndexed($items) { i, $item in
    HStack {
        Text("Index \(i)")
        TextField("", text: $item.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Philip. It's a good idea. But at the moment, with your wrapper the app crashes if you try to delete the last row.

Comment: You could replace `data[i]` by 
`Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }).projectedValue`
to resolve the problem. But I'm not sure if this is the clearest way to do it and how it impacts performance.

Comment: @Adrien oh, so my wrapper gets uglier :D I don't think this will cause dramatic performance problems, reading from array is O(1). I think that source code of new `List($data)` should have something similar too=) Also why you you call `projectedValue`? AFAIK it's only needed for "$" to work, works fine with just init to me

Comment: You are right about `projectedValue`. You're also right about how ugly this edit is. But I don't know of any other way to avoid this crash with an out-of-bounds error than to create these custom binding instances.

Comment: It's brilliant. And it will be very useful, 

Comment: @Adrien tnx for your tips. I am using the new binding syntax and deleting the `item` from the array by its `index` using `remove(at: index)` method but I am still getting array out of bounds error. I made sure the index that I am passing is correct and well within bounds. So, is there anything that I am missing here? I thought the new binding syntax was supposed to solve this issue.

Comment: Actually, I found the issue and it's a weird one. I had the code for removing the item inside an `animation` block and this was causing the error. Getting rid of the animation block got rid of the array out-of-bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

If your items are Equatable, you can use `firstIndex(of:)` to get their index:

```
List($data) { $item in
    HStack {
        Text("Index \(data.firstIndex(of: item)! + 1)")
        TextField("", text: $item.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Items don't need to be Equatable, we can use `firstIndex (where: {$0.id == id})` 
But the complexity of `firstIndex` is O(n) (n = length), so O(n ^ 2) for the whole ForEach. We may be able to find better.