# Deleting row in Form results in Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I have the following code, which will compile only in Xcode 13 beta, not in Xcode 12. **The project is targeting iOS 13 and up.** Note that it uses the new syntax that can pass a binding to an array element, which is what I need in my project (but this demo code could do without).

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: MyModel
    
    init() {
        self.model = MyModel(components: ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot"])
    }
}

struct MyModel {
    var components: [String]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Components")) {
                    ForEach(self.$viewModel.model.components, id: \.self) { $component in
                        Text(component)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }

    private func delete(_ indices: IndexSet) {
        for index in indices {
            self.viewModel.model.components.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the ContentView() must be injected with the correct environment object, i.e.:

```
struct FormDeleteCrashDemo_iOS13App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(MyViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code **on iPad or iPhone running iOS 14**, the user can swipe-left-to-delete. Deleting the bottom row is fine. Deleting any other row will crash with the following error:

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

When I replace the `Form` with `List`, then the crash does not occur. Why?

Comment: Did not crush. Run on Xcode 13 and iOS 15.

Comment: works without any problems for me using macos 12, xcode 13, targets macos 12 and ios15, 
tested on real devices, iPhone, mac.

Comment: Sorry, edited to add note about iOS version. Specifically, it crashes on iOS 14.

Comment: is the List with binding available for ios13 or ios14? I thought it was only for ios15+.

Comment: @workingdog it's available on iOS13. Otherwise, the author would not have been able to run the app.

Comment: are you sure about that, List with binding is a very recent addition, and the app does not run it crashes.

Comment: @workingdog it crashes exactly with and `ForEach` inside `Form`, with `List` it works fine too. So it's a bug

Comment: ok, sorry, it worked well for me on ios15 and obviously not on ios14, hence my "wrong" deduction.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. Crash happens exactly with `Form`(works fine with `List`)

I've reported it it to [feedback assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/), so let's hope it'll be fixed before release.

Meanwhile you can try this `CustomForEach`, inspired by my [ListIndexed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68853793/3585796). All animations looks totally fine.

```
struct CustomForEach<Data: MutableCollection&RandomAccessCollection, RowContent: View, ID: Hashable>: View, DynamicViewContent where Data.Index : Hashable
{
    let forEach: ForEach<[(Data.Index, Data.Element)], ID, RowContent>
    
    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element.ID == ID {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: \.1.id
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
        }
    }
    
    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: (\.1 as KeyPath<(Data.Index, Data.Element), Data.Element>).appending(path: id)
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
        }
    }
    
    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) where ID == Data.Element {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: \.1
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        forEach
    }
    
    var data: [(Data.Index, Data.Element)] {
        forEach.data
    }
}
```